# PHP Web Service Using nusoup give error "error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name"

Tags: php, web-services

I'm learning how to create a web service using C# and PHP and the C# one is working but the PHP one is giving me an error:

error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

when I click on the wsdl, and the PHP client is not returning anything my code is like this:

The Server (PHPWebService.php):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Web Service</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    require "lib/nusoap.php";

    function MyFunction($name){
        return $name;
    }

    $server = new nusoap_server();
    $server->configureWSDL("MyPHPWebService","urn:PHPWebService");

    $server->register("MyFunction",array("name"=>"xsd:string"),array("return"=>"xsd:string"));

    if(isset($HTTP_Raw_POST_DATA)){
        $HTTP_Raw_POST_DATA = $HTTP_Raw_POST_DATA;
    }else{
        $HTTP_Raw_POST_DATA = "No Name!";
    }
    $server->service($HTTP_Raw_POST_DATA)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the client (PHPClient.php):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Web Service Client</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    require "lib/nusoap.php";
    $client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/PHPWebService/PHPWebService.php?wsdl");
    $response = $client->call("name",array("name"=>"Emad Zedan"));
    echo $response;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your seeing is because the NuSOAP client is trying to read the HTML that your server file is outputting.

If you remove the all the HTML from PHPWebService.php (i.e. everything that isn't between the `<?php` `?>` tags), the error should go away.